# How to delete an application from IBM UrbanCode Deploy using REST API?

Tags: rest, urbancode, udeploy

As part of some integration testing we are creating a uDeploy application, checking it exists and then hoping to delete it after to cleanup.

Looking at the documentation here: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS4GSP_6.2.2/com.ibm.udeploy.api.doc/topics/rest_cli_application.html and googling around, I can't find an API endpoint to delete the created application.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Deleting an application is not part of the official and documented API and hence not supported. But it can be done with help of the unsupported API:

curl --user {USERNAME} -k "https://ucdserver.domain.com:8443/rest/deploy/application/{APPLICATION-ID}" -X DELETE